# Debugger recommendation

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone recommend a Linux-based C++ debugger to use with ROS?  I'm using Ubuntu 10.4 with electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12103/debugger-recommendation/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-11-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think, there are no options here. GDB is pretty good for it. You can use IDE (KDevelop, as example, it handles with CMake system by default) or graphical front-end (ddd or something like this), if console is too uncomfortable.

---

Originally posted by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) with karma: 546 on 2011-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5